# What do Contextual Filters filter against?

Tags: 8, views

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to understand contextual filters for about 6 months now so I thought I'd give up and finally ask. Most recently I read [this article on cofiguring contextual filters](https://www.drupal.org/node/1578564), which renewed my confusion and frustration on this topic.

Normally in query or procedural languages when you filter something, you specify 2 or 3 things;

1. The value to filter (e.g. "blonde")
2. The place to look for the values (e.g. the "hair color" column)
3. Optionally, the operator to use.

My understanding is that contextual filters only use the "equal to" operator, so I'll leave out 3.

For example, if I wanted to filter a `nodes` table on all nodes whose value in the `title` column is equal to the contents of the `my_title` variable, then in SQL I'd write something like this;

```
SELECT * FROM nodes WHERE title = @my_title
```

There's a left hand side (title) and right hand side (my_title). But in the Contextual views section of the view I can only pick the dynamic value to check against (the equivalent of `my_title`) but where do I pick what I'm actually filtering on (ie. the title column)?

[image]

As far as I can tell this is telling the filter to filter on the ID of the current page. Which is fine, but what am I filtering? What are the left and right hand operators to the filtering operation?

Comment: The field you choose for a contextual filter is the "left side" (column). In your example, you've chosen the "Content: ID" filter so nid is always the left. The value it checks for (the right side) is from the inner configuration.

Comment: @sonfd what's "the inner configuration"? I can't tell from your comment what the left and right hand sides are and where they come from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, a view is used to show data for a list of entities. View filters are used to select (or filter) which entities are handled by the view; contextual filters are used to select the entities basing on the values passed in the URL.

For example, the *Files* view that comes with Drupal 8 has two pages: one whose path is /admin/content/files and one whose path is /admin/content/files/usage/%.

> [image: screenshot]

The second page shows data (the entity label and the entity type for the entity containing a reference to the file; the module managing the file relationship; the number of times the file is used by the entity) for the file whose ID is passed in the view path.

> [image: screenshot]

When I visit /admin/content/files/usage/3 on the test site I created, the view shows the following data.

> [image: screenshot]

On /admin/content/files/usage/2, the view shows the following data.

> [image: screenshot]

Using as another example a default view that is already enabled on /admin/structure/views, the *Taxonomy term* view has a page shown on /taxonomy/term/% which uses the *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* contextual filter.

> [image: screenshot]

It shows all the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is passed in the URL. In the test site I am using, /taxonomy/term/1 shows all the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is 1 (the *test* taxonomy term), while /taxonomy/term/2 shows all the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is 2 (the *view* taxonomy term).

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Contextual filters are still filters, as they select (or filter) the entities from which the data is taken. The difference is that their values are passed from the view URL, not from a form like the filters set in the *Filter criteria* section.

The number of entities from which the data is taken and what entities are handled by the contextual filter is hard-coded in the class implementing the contextual filter: *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* selects all the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is equal to the value passed in the URL, which could be zero or more than one node, while *Content: ID* selects only the node whose ID is passed in the URL; *User: Created* selects all the user accounts that have been created at the time passed in the URL.
The category of the contextual filter (another value set by the the class implementing the contextual filter), which is shown in the contextual filter name, helps to understand which entities a contextual filter selects: *Content: Has taxonomy term ID* and *Content: ID* select nodes, while *User: Created* selects users.

Comment: How does views know what to filter the entities on though? In your example you've told views that "File ID" is a value it should pull out from the context, but where are you telling views what to do with it? Is it just assumed that the view should show you nodes with IDs matching the context value?

Comment: No, the view isn't showing the nodes with an ID matching the passed value. The contextual filter is *File: File ID*, not *Content: ID*. A view is always showing data for specific entities; that is not something you need to tell the view. You just tell the view which entities to show, when you select the type of view, and when you add the view filters.

Comment: `The contextual filter is File: File ID` - I don't understand what this means. What's the difference between a view that has this contextual filter and one that doesn't?

Comment: A view without contextual filters cannot use the values passed in the URL to select for which entities show the data. If I have a view block that is shown in node/[node-id], without the _Content: ID_ contextual filter, it cannot understand to use the node ID passed in the URL to show the data for that node.

Comment: There are many contextual filters, each of them with a specific functionality. _File: File ID_ is for identifiers of the File entity, _Content: ID_ is for the node identifiers, _Content: Has taxonomy term ID_ is for the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is passed on the URL. What appears in a URL is just a string. A view needs to know what that string is; that is why there are different contextual filters.

Comment: So if I use the _File: File ID_ contextual filter, I understand that the file ID is made available to the view for filtering, but where do we tell the view to then only display that file? Is that somehow baked into the logic of the contextual filter?

Comment: Yes, contextual filters tell a view it can use a parameter passed in the URL and what exactly that parameter is.

Comment: The purpose of contextual filters is still to display a subset of all the available entities. If you have a view block shown in _node/%_ which uses a _Content: ID_ contextual filter, that contextual filter is telling the view to show data from a single node, whose ID is passed in the URL; in the default view on /taxonomy/term/%, the _Content: Has taxonomy term ID_ contextual filter it uses is telling the view to show data from all the nodes using the taxonomy term whose ID is passed in the URL.

Comment: How many entities are shown is decided from the contextual filter. As I said, the _Content: Has taxonomy term ID_ contextual filter shows data from one or more nodes, while the _Content: ID_ contextual filter shows data only from a single node. The _Content: Authored by_ contextual filter shows data from all the nodes authored by a user.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, they've really helped and I don't think I'd have gotten there without them! I'm going to mark this as the answer. Patrick Kenny's was good as well as the SQL view option was really helpful in understanding the functionality, but I think this addresses the question more directly.

Answer (score 5):

In Views, if you go into the Settings (`/admin/structure/views/settings`), you can check the box **Show the SQL query** to see the magic.

I made a very simple view of content.  Here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE node_field_data.status = '1'
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

Next I added a contextual filter for **Content: ID** and accepted the defaults.

**In this case, the SQL query does not change.**  This is because "Display all results for the specified field" is the default for **When the filter value is NOT available** in the contextual filter settings.

The query only changes if the contextual filter is provided with a value. (To provide a dummy value for testing purposes, you can input a value in **Preview with contextual filters**.)

Here, I tested by inputting `1` for **Preview with contextual filters**, which gave me this query:

```
SELECT node_field_data.created AS node_field_data_created, node_field_data.nid AS nid
FROM
{node_field_data} node_field_data
WHERE ((node_field_data.nid = '1')) AND (node_field_data.status = '1')
ORDER BY node_field_data_created DESC
LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

"Contextual filters" is a hard-to-understand name, but back in Drupal 6 (as long as I'm remembering right) this was called "Arguments", which makes more sense to me.

Comment: That "Show the SQL query" setting is super helpful, thanks! In your example, how does views decide to compare "1" to the value of "nid"? The "Content: ID" filter presumably tells views where to get the context value from (which you've set to 1 manually in your example), but where does it decide to compare it to nid?

Comment: `how does views decide to compare "1" to the value of "nid"?`  You configure this in the URL path (of the view, with placeholders `%`) and in the contextual filter settings for the view.  You set this config to match what you want to happen; for an example, look at the core taxonomy terms view: `/admin/structure/views/view_taxonomy_term`.

Comment: I understand that the URL provides the value for the ID (in this example 1) but where is it that views knows to compare that value to the node ID for the purpose of filtering? Is that just baked into the filter somehow?

Comment: In this case, I added a **Content ID** filter, which is set to operate on the node ID.  That's just how the filter is defined.  Of course it's possible to write your own contextual filter plugin if you want to do something more complicated.  You can also use multiple placeholders in the URL to use multiple contextual filters. In that case, you have to set the order in the view for which filter is which placeholder.